# Websockets in .NET Core 2.0 - receiving messages in chunks

Tags: .net, websocket, .net-core

I have a piece of code that receives messages from websocket. It works correctly in .NET 4.6.1, but not in .NET Core 2.0.

Everything works correctly in NET Core version, if the message is smaller than the buffer size. When it's larger, **WebSocketConnection.ReceiveAsync** keeps reading chunks of 512 bytes, and **messageReceiveResult.EndOfMessage** is never set to **true**.

Size of the buffer is set to this small value for test purposes.

Do you think there's any other option besides setting the buffer size to some arbitrary large value?

Here's the code:

```
while (WebSocketConnection.State == System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketState.Open)
{
var compoundBuffer = new List<byte>();
var messageReceiveResult = new WebSocketReceiveResult(0, WebSocketMessageType.Close, false);
byte[] buffer = new byte[512];

while (!messageReceiveResult.EndOfMessage)
{
    // read one message until the end
    messageReceiveResult = await WebSocketConnection.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), cancellationToken);

    if (messageReceiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
    {
        byte[] readBytes = new byte[messageReceiveResult.Count];
        Array.Copy(buffer, readBytes, messageReceiveResult.Count);
        compoundBuffer.AddRange(readBytes);
    }
}
// get string message
string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(compoundBuffer.ToArray());
```

}

Has anyone encountered similar problem?

Answer (score 2):

FYI, this has been fixed in upcoming release: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/28097#event-1536476277

Thanks to the .NET Framework team for taking care of this issue!